# I would like to create a live video streaming site in php and WebRTC

Tags: php, websocket, webrtc, php-7

I have reached a good stage in programming (php), but there are some things that hinder me in progress, which is that I cannot create some types of sites and use some APIs, and sites that hinder me in progress

### **And the first problem that hinders me is: -**

I would like to create a live video streaming site and have read and found that I have to use webRTC, but I only found a two-person connection or a server used to connect to more than two people, but that is the point. I did not find a source for learning or an application example that shows me what I want, is there any application available in php and webRTC so that I can learn and please if there is an open source application and not documented, because **I am not strong in the English language, I am in the stage of learning**

When I understand and I can program the first obstacle, which is a live broadcast video, I will request your help again in some problems, which are sms api, visa api, paypal api and imap in php

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may have already realised WebRTC knows how to communicate with other peers, but it doesn’t know how to discover these other peers. For discovery you can try Ably - use it as a realtime signalling platform in collaboration with WebRTC.

I'd really recommend having a look through Ably's WebRTC tutorial series. More specifically there's a tutorial focussed on [video calling using WebRTC and Ably](http://go.ably.com/webrtc-videocalling-tutorial). I hope that helps, or is at least a good place to start.